# Springboot application on Tomcat is giving exception on startup at deployment

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot Application that I am trying to deploy on Tomcat.
I am getting the following error on statup.

```
ar]
2015-06-21 19:04:26.392 ERROR 7568 --- [apr-8080-exec-4] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
ion               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedde
d container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationE
xception: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageFilter': Initialization of bea
n failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.
boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.cont
ext.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
```

This is my spring boot initializer code.

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {   
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }    
}
```

What am I missing here.

as requested here is the gradle .

```
buildscript {
    ext {

        springBootVersion1= '1.2.3.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        //maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'



war {
    baseName = 'rabbitmq-ws-jar-to-war'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   // maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
   // maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }

   // flatDir {
   //   dirs 'lib'
   // }
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:${springBootVersion1}")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion1}")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion1}")
    {
    exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
  }
  //compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:${springBootVersion1}")


    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.3.0.RELEASE")

    providedCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth-parent:2.0.7.RELEASE")

    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate:3.3.2.GA")
    //compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final")
    //compile("org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:2.0.8")
    compile("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2")
    compile("org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.0.Final")


  compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")

   compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
   compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
   compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4")
    compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")

    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")

    compile("com.github.davidmarquis:fluent-interface-proxy:1.3.0")
    compile("org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:${springBootVersion1}")
    compile("com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.5.1")
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.2.2')

    //compile("org.nigajuan.rabbit.management.client:rabbit-management-client:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: add your pom.xml or build.gradle file

Comment: Thanks . I have added the gradle file.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I have been experiencing the same problem...

Comment: Hello - i have created a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240159/spring-boot-war-file-on-tomcat-errorpagefilter-cannot-be-cast-to-tomcatembedded